# Launching tensorboard error - ImportError: cannot import name weakref

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

With python 2.7 on a mac with tensorflow and running 
`tensorboard --logdir= directory/wheremylog/fileis` produces the following error `ImportError: cannot import name weakref`

I've seen several folks remedy the issue with `pip install backports.weakref`
 but that requirement is already satisfied for me. `Requirement already satisfied: backports.weakref in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

I am out of ideas and am really keen to get tensorboard working.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For those with the same problem I was able to fix it through the following:
1) find where your tensorflow lives `pip show tensorflow` and look at the location line, copy it.

2) For me it was `cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`

3) `cd tensorflow/python/lib`

4) `open tf_should_use.py`

5) In your python editor replace line 28 `from backports import weakref` with `import weakref` and save the file.